# Need help simplifying this Boolean expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

From my textbook, by using distributive law, its able to simplify:

$[(p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)] \land q$

To:

$[p \land (\lnot q \lor q)] \land q $

I don't know how to get to this step, and here is how I've tried by distributing the first expression :

$[(p \lor p) \land (p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p) \land (\lnot q \lor q)] \land q$

If I try continue to expand this, it will become very complex. I think I'm doing this in the wrong way and I will appreciate it very much if anyone can explain how the textbook got the simplified answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Distributive law goes *both ways*, because it is an equivalence.

That is, using the Distributive Law you can go from $p \land (\neg q \lor q)$ to $(p \land \neg q) \lor (p \land q)$, but you can use that same Distributive Law to go from the latter to the former, and that is what they did here.

I believe the name is somewhat to blame for the fact that so many students, like you, only think of the Distributive Law going one way, because going from $(p \land \neg q) \lor (p \land q)$ to $p \land (\neg q \lor q)$ does not feel like Distribution, but rather as a kind of 'Un-Distribution' or 'Reverse Distribution', or maybe even 'Taking out a common Factor' ... but it is still called Distribution in logic.

Comment: @Bram28   ahh I see, thank you. I've tried to test the result on truth table, and the two expression are indeed equivalent, however, is there a way to prove their equivalency without using truth table? Is it possible to use the distributive law on [(p∧¬q)∨(p∧q)] and arrive at [p∧(¬q∨q)] ? It seems it just goes on forever with the expansion.

Comment: @IhavelowIQ Yes. This is what I tried to say in my Answer: going from $[(p \land \neg q) \lor (p \land q)]$ to $[p \land (\neg q \lor q)]$ *is* using the Distributive Law.

Comment: @IhavelowIQ All these laws in Boolean algebra go both ways. For example, using DeMorgan you can go from $\neg (p \lor q)$ to $\neg p \land \neg q$, but going from $\neg p \land \neg q$ to $\neg (p \lor q)$ is *also* using the DeMorgan's law, since the DeMorgan's law is an equivalence.  So you can go back and forth using the same law. Same for Distribution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed your edited message. You are right, I was only thinking of going one way (taught in the book), and  [(p∧¬q)∨(p∧q)] to [p∧(¬q∨q)] was definitely not apparent for me. But thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @IhavelowIQ ok, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 5):

$$[(\color{blue}{p} \land \lnot q) \lor (\color{blue}{p} \land q)] \land q \equiv [\color{blue}{p} \land (\color{red}{{\lnot q \lor q}})] \land q\tag{distributivity}$$

$$ \equiv (\color{blue}{p} \land \color{red} \top) \land q$$

$$\equiv \color{blue}{p} \land q$$

That is, the distributive law declares that $$[p\land (\lnot q \lor q)] \equiv [(p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)]$$  That means that it is the same law when we write it: $$[(p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land q)] \equiv [p\land (\lnot q \lor q)]$$

---

**Addendum**

[image]

[image]

[image]